# Calculation of pulse energy usring the beam profile of the light source

Tags: optics, laser

Is it possible to calculate the peak pulse power of a light source using its beam profile say Gaussian?

Comment: Do you have any more information that that? I can think of ways to involve the beam profile in the calculation depending on what you measure. But that alone is not enough information.

Comment: We perfomed a knife edge test to exactly determine the FWHM of the profile . Close fit to a gaussian. By additional information you mean rep rate and average power ?

Comment: Yes. You need some measurement of power. Maybe your profile has that information. But FWHM alone isnt enough either.

Comment: You need pulse energy and pulse duration to determine peak power. Pulse energy can be derived from average power and rep rate. Then you need to measure the pulse duration. Peak power is not dependent on space (its in watts). So a beam profile is useless for a peak power measurement. From pulse energy and beam profile you can get fluence (J/m²) and with pulse duration you can find intensity (W/m²).